# Graph REST API - Cannot access a DriveItem's ListItem

Tags: sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api, rest

I'm using the rest api to access my drive's items.
I can access the items perfectly fine like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{driveid}}/items/{{folderid}}/children
```

But this is where my problems lie:

This:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{driveid}}/items/{{folderid}}/children?expand=fields
```

Gives this result:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Could not find a property named 'fields' on type 'oneDrive.item'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-09-02T10:50:12",
            "request-id": "075bf9b7-c93a-43d2-a1ed-bd4563399f1a",
            "client-request-id": "075bf9b7-c93a-43d2-a1ed-bd4563399f1a"
        }
    }
}
```

And this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{driveid}}/items/{{folderid}}/children?expand=listitem
```

Gives this result:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Could not find a property named 'listitem' on type 'oneDrive.item'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-09-02T10:50:30",
            "request-id": "2db87d5f-fbe9-42ad-a61e-a377bafafcad",
            "client-request-id": "2db87d5f-fbe9-42ad-a61e-a377bafafcad"
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried `?$expand=fields` and that gives me this message:

```
"Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Could not find a property named 'fields' on type 'microsoft.graph.driveItem'."
```

What am I doing wrong? Because I have another separate SharePoint site and the `?expand=listitem` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get a decent workaround by using the Graph SDK:

```
graphClient
.Sites[SiteID]
.Drives[DriveID]
.Items[FolderID]
.Children
.Request()
.Expand(item => item.ListItem)
.GetAsync();
```